# Refresh token can be refreshed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dart, flutter, amazon-cognito

I am working with AWS Cognito, doing manually the requests with dart to the api and getting the tokens, is it posible to refresh the refresh token before the time to expires?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up a long validity period for the Refresh Token Between 1 day and 3650 days, inclusive of the created date.

At the moment, there is no direct way to Refresh the Refresh token unless you store the credentials of the user (Which is not recommended).

Comment: I found a re:Post question related to this as well. Maybe enough upvotes there get this feature added? https://repost.aws/questions/QUCStInJAhSXGChSESAwUBaQ/cognito-make-auth-tokens-validity-dependent-on-users-activity